# Dynamically added Jquery remove button not working

Tags: jquery, button, document-ready

This is no doubt simple, but my lack of knowledge about jquery makes it complex for me. Basically I have this code:

```
$(document).ready( 
    function() {
    $( "#remove")
    .click(function() {
        alert("I have been clicked!");
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }); 
});
```

I add a button to a table meant to remove it's row (see above code). The button is as follows:

```
<td ><button id='remove' type='button'>Remove</button></td>
```

However, it does nothing when clicked. I think this may have something to do with the fact the button is created after the document is loaded... no idea what to do about it, though.

Comment: try to investigate in Firebug. may b u r not able to select it properly using $() selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( "td").on('click', '#remove', function() {
        alert("I have been clicked!");
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

As you're trying to add button dynamically so you need delegate event handler (aka, live event).

An in ***jQuery > 1.7*** delegate event declare as

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

For more detail see [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

You have another option called [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) and its declaration process is:

```
$(container).delegate(target, eventName, handlerFunction);
```

So for your case it will look like:

```
$('td').delegate('#remove', 'click', function() {
      alert("I have been clicked!");
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

#### Note

here `container` means the holder of `#remove` button which belong to DOM at page load. From you post it seem `td`, you may have something else (any valid [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors))

#### If you can't detect you `container` for `#remove` then use `$(document)` or `$('body')` instead of `$('td')`.

Comment: 1. Holy crap that was fast.
2. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: @MirroredFate I try to explain in my answer

Comment: The containing row is also dynamically generated, so using "td" won't work. I tried using the table, but that didn't work. I will keep reading the linked documentation to try and find an answer. Once I get one, I will mark this.

Comment: @MirroredFate I mentioned in my note that you have to set a container that should belong to dom at page load, otherwise use `$(document)` or `$('body')`.

Comment: If you have jQuery 1.7+ you really should update to using `.on()`. Delegate will still work, but `on` is the preferred syntax. Delegate isn't deprecated yet, but it's probably on the chopping block for some point in the future.